# Error Loading Design Unresolved Reference

Tags: verilog, verification

DUT:

```
module ANDgate(a, b, c);
input a;
input b;
output c;
assign c = a & b;
endmodule
```

TESTBENCH: Without task

```
`include "simple_task.v"    
module task_calling();
  reg tb_a;
  reg tb_b;
  wire tb_c;  
 
ANDgate myAND (
  .a(tb_a),
  .b(tb_b),
  .c(tb_c));

always
  begin 
    task_ANDinputs(tb_a, tb_b);
    $display ("time = ", $time, " a = %d, b=%d, c=%d", tb_a, tb_b, tb_c);
  end  

endmodule
```

TASK:

```
`include "ANDgate.v"
module simple_task();

task task_ANDinputs(output x, output y);

begin
  x = 1'b1;
  y = 1'b0;
end

endtask

endmodule
```

There is no compilation error, but it says:

> ERROR LOADING DESIGN

Is there a problem with my code? The only use of the task is to input 1 and 0 to `x` and `y` respectively. And this is the detailed error:

> ** Error: (vsim-3043) C:/altera/14.1/Simple Task 2/task_calling.v(14): Unresolved reference to 'task_ANDinputs'.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not include another module within the module/endmodule keywords.  I no longer get errors when I make the following changes:

**task_calling.v:**

```
`include "ANDgate.v"

module task_calling();

`include "simple_task.v"
  reg tb_a;
  reg tb_b;
  wire tb_c;  

ANDgate myAND (
  .a(tb_a),
  .b(tb_b),
  .c(tb_c));

initial
  begin 
    task_ANDinputs(tb_a, tb_b);
    $display ("time = ", $time, " a = %d, b=%d, c=%d", tb_a, tb_b, tb_c);
  end  

endmodule
```

**simple_task.v:**

```
task task_ANDinputs(output x, output y);

begin
  x = 1'b1;
  y = 1'b0;
end

endtask
```

I changed your `always` to an `initial` to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: I found some answer about my problem, it said I should instantiate the module where the task is located. Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735424/task-in-verilog